# How to send a signal to the client when a database row changes state?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Say I have a sql server table with a 'UserState" column.

What options do I have to update the browser client (using websockets/signalR) when the UserStatus column changes?

Does the backend c# code have to poll for chances?

Comment: One way is to use SqlDependency: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency

Comment: you need observer pattern depending on the publisher subscriber way to implement the DB actions that will raise flag for those who are subscribe on DB events you can catch all DB updates

Answer (score 0):

Is value of your *UserState* column changing from your application ? If the answer is yes, the *observer pattern* is exactly what you are looking for.

Even if your project uses Entity Framework to perform database actions, there is a very useful article here.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/998560/Customer-Invoicing-System-Applying-Visitor-Design